Non-Interactive Login for Dataverse (TDS Endpoint)
I would like to connect a Laravel application to my Microsoft Dynamics tables. Success would enable us to write Laravel models on top of the Dynamics tables for read operations.
I've successfully exposed the tables via the TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol. I'm able to access those tables and write SQL queries in Azure Data Studio, but only after an interactive login (Authentication Type: Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA support).
Is it possible to initiate a server-to-server authentication against the TDS endpoint?
